# (Не)свойственные

Tags: грамматика

(Не)свойственные им качества — как правильно писать слово с -не-?

Answer (score 1):

Да, в данном контексте "не" следует писать раздельно, т.к. имеется зависимое слово "им".

Comment: Здесь - похоже да. Но вообще к этому правилу надо относиться с большой осторожностью. Больно уж много появилось сейчас нечленимых терминов с "не". Даже "несвойственный" в принципе может означать чужой, чужеродный.

Answer (score 1):

Да нет же! "Свойственнный (несвойственный) - это прилагательное, и раздельно при наличии зависимого слова будет написано, если это зависимое начинается с "НИ".  ("Несвойственные им", но  "нисколько им не свойственные") .Проверим заменой на синоним - чужой для них, чужеродный (см. комментарий выше). Вообще для именных прилагательных при всем разнообразии условий замена на синоним помогает отличить отрицание с "НЕ" - пиши раздельно- от противоположного признака - пиши слитно. (приставка "НЕ" образует антоним)

Answer (score 0):

Возможны оба варианта. Скорее всего - раздельно, т. к. "им качества" можно воспринять как зависимые слова. Если только не предполагается, что "несвойственный" - устоявшийся термин,  не сводящийся к отрицанию "свойственного".

Контекст можно посмотреть?